# passing form textbox value to another form in same project

Tags: vb.net

I currently have 2 forms.  1 holds user data and is modifiable.  The other is a display/read only form.

I am trying to pull data (tbUSI.text) from ReportSettings and pass it to Form1 and display it on my UserData.text control.

I have tried using public properties but to no avail.  I would rather use public properties, since its cleaner.  Here is the code im using to set the property:

```
Public Property UserSignedInto As String
        Get
            Return tbUSI.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
        End Set
    End Property
```

Here is my code attempting to call that property on the main form (form1)

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        UserData.text = UserSignedInto
End Sub
```

It doesn't pull anything, the textbox on my main form is blank.

Comment: you just created a new `ReportSettings` instance on the line before - how could it have user input in it?

Comment: Maybe i misread that on the forum i grabbed that code from.  Anyway, how do i call a public property on another form?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

```
SCCMReports = New ReportSettings
UserData.text = SCCMReports.UserSignedInto
```

When was the `SCCMReports` form ever displayed to the user?  Since it was never displayed, its `tbUSI.Text` value will of course be empty because the user never had an opportunity to enter text.

It sounds like you need a reference to an *existing* instance of `ReportSettings`, rather than creating a *new* instance.  Where do you have that existing instance?

If `Form1` created the instance in another block of code, store it in a class-level member on `Form1`  (perhaps called `SCCMReportsInstance` or something of that nature).  When the instance is created, set it to the value of that property and reference that property in your code:

```
UserData.text = Me.SCCMReportsInstance.UserSignedInto
```

If the `ReportSettings` form is instead creating the instance of `Form1` then it can pass a reference to itself.  You'd still have a property on `Form1`, it would just be set in the constructor.  Something like this:

```
Sub New(ByVal sccmReportsInstance As ReportSettings)
    Me.SCCMReportsInstance = sccmReportsInstance
End Sub
```

So when initializing the `Form1` instance, you'd pass the reference:

```
Dim form1 As Form1
form1 = New Form1(Me)
form1.Show()
```

Any way you go about it, you need to access the *existing* instance of the displayed form in order to access its properties.  A new instance would have new versions of those properties and wouldn't have the same values.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  ReportSettings is its own form and is called modally to fill out some settings that i save to the registry.  On the main form (form1), i want to call a textbox.text control from ReportSettings and pass it to a textbox control on the main form.  How would i go about doing that?

Comment: @dmj12508: The same principle applies regardless of which forms create instances of which other forms.  The form which has the value exposes it as a public property, and the form which has a reference to that form reads that property from that reference.

Comment: Since UserSignedInto is a public property of ReportSettings, why am  i unable to call that property on form1???

Comment: Like, shouldnt this work?  tbUSI.Text = ReportSettings.UserSignedInto

Comment: @dmj12508: You *can*, as long as that instance of `Form1` has a reference to *the existing instance* of `ReportSettings`.  In your code you're creating a *new* instance, which is different.  You seem to be confusing *static* (`Shared` in VB) with *instance* values.  Consider a real-world example... You have a car, and you put something in the glove compartment. If you create another car of the same model, can you get that object out of the second car's glove compartment? Clearly not, because that object isn't in the second car, it's in the first one.

Comment: Ahh, i get it now.  I need  to set a reference to the existing instance of ReportSettings.  How can i set a reference to the existing ReportSettings form?

Comment: @dmj12508: There are many ways to do that, and I'm afraid I don't know enough about how your forms interact to be very specific. If the code which creates the instance of `Form1` has a reference to the instance of `ReportSettings`, then it can pass that reference to `Form1`'s constructor for example. Or set a public property on `Form1` to include that reference. Or if `Form1` creates the instance of `ReportSettings` then it already has that reference and just needs to keep it somewhere (such as a private property). Or something else, depending on how the forms interact with one another.

Comment: I just have a button that opens up ReportSettings and on ReportSettings i have an exit to main form button, thats the extent of the interaction.  Any help you can provide would be awesome as im pulling hair out

Comment: The button that "opens ReportSettings"... Is that on Form1? Presumably then there is code on Form1 which creates and shows ReportSettings? If that's the case then that specific variable of ReportSettings on which you call .Show() is exactly the variable you'd get the data from. When you create/show it, store it in a class-level variable on Form1 so other methods on Form1 can access it.

Comment: Yes it resides on Form1.  I call it like this: ReportSettings.ShowDialog()

I want to be able to access the data on ReportSettings on form1 all the time, so when form1 loads, it has the information from reportsettings populated in their intended fields

Comment: @dmj12508: Well, if Form1 *creates* a ReportSettings instance then clearly Form1 can't have a reference to that instance when Form1 is created. But once it creates that instance, it can *keep* that reference. Just create a private property of type ReportSettings in the Form1 class and set its value to the ReportSettings instance when that instance is created. Then from that point forward any code on Form1 can access that same ReportSettings instance from that property.